# How to count non zeros for categories in grouped data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have created the following data frame

```
lst = [('Ron','Math',10),('Ron','Math',0),('Ron','Math',5),('Ron','Math',7),('Rick','Science',10),('Rick','Science',0),('Rick','Science',0),('Rick','Science',0),('Rick','Science',7)]
labels=['Student','Subject','Grades']        
t=pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst,columns=labels)
```

I managed to count number of zeros between two non zero values by doing the following:

```
df=t[t!=0].reset_index()
df['a'] = df['index'] - df['index'].shift(1)
df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

However, I would like to do this for each categories (Student and subject), I have tried to group by student and subject and use previous code as a function but it did not work. Any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Can you give a more meaningful name of 'a'? It is not so clear about the literal meaning of "count number of zeros between two non zero values" and the implementation of `df['a'] = df['index'] - df['index'].shift(1)` since df['a'] is always be [NaN, 1, 1, ...]. @SYN

Comment: Hi David, a is the step count between non zero elements, it shows how many zeros there are between non zero elements.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The answer I got for running code mentioned above is                                
 index           
                 Student Subject Grades a
0 0 Ron Math 10.0 NaN
2 2 Ron Math 5.0 2.0
3 3 Ron Math 7.0 1.0
4 4 Rick Science 10.0 1.0
8 8 Rick Science 7.0 4.0                                                                            I was hoping to see the same after grouping by student and subject